# Neo4j:Generate relationship between nodes retrieved using Java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

What I have done:

- I have created nodes with multiple properties like name,Age,Location,Gender etc.
- I want to retrieve nodes which have matching property values and create a relationship   between them.(Eg nodes which have same age or same location).

I have done this as follows:

```
   void query()
{
    ExecutionResult result;
    Transaction tx=null;
    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );

    try
    {
        String name="Female";
        tx=graphDb.beginTx();

        result=engine.execute("start n=node(*) where has(n.City) with n.City as city, collect(n) as nodelist, count(*) as count where count > 1 return city, nodelist, count");

        System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
        tx.success();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        tx.failure();
    }
    finally
    {
        tx.finish();
    }

}
```

The nodelist gives me the nodes with same properties .
I want to create a relationship between these nodes.

How can I point to the nodes in the nodelist?
Also,please suggest other alternative ways of doing the same

Comment: Don't create an execution-engine per query method, create it once at startup and keep it around.

Answer (score 1):

To get hold of the nodes in nodelist:

```
Iterator<Map<String,Object>> it=result.iterator ();
if(it.hasNext()) {
  Map<String,Object> row=it.next();
  List<Node> nodelist=(List<Node>) row.get("nodelist");
}
```

You haven't specified what kinds of relationships you want to create - take a look at [Create or Merge](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-write.html) and if applicable, [Foreach](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-foreach.html) - maybe you can write one Cypher query to do it all.

Comment: I want to create a simple KNOWS relationship between all the nodes present in the nodelist .Can you help me with how a single cypher query will help me get all nodes with matching property values and create relationship between them  ?

Comment: I went through the foreach ,and i want to create a relationship as follows between all the nodes in the nodelist as follows .CREATE (node1)<-[:REL1]-(n { knows:'Property_Female' })-[:REL2]->(node2)).My nodes here are those which I get in  the nodelist.I am unable to understand how to point to nodes in the nodelist inorder to use them in the create relationship cypher query